# Ubuntu Remote Desktop through Real VNC error "The connection closed unexpectedly"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote, vnc, remote-desktop

I have installed ubuntu on a PC at a remote site. Now I wanted to access it from my home. I got it after I promptly followed the instructions on https://linuxhint.com/disable-screen-lock-ubuntu/ That is on Ubuntu, I unlocked the automatic screen locking and enabled automatic login. This was fine. I was able to access the ubuntu PC for a good two days sitting in my home.  Don't know what happened: suddenly  I lost connection with Real VNC displaying following error message on my laptop. I could not access it and I came back to the remote site and I see the settings remained same. Don't know why and what happened?

**Note**: I got this message previously when I had good connection. I would just restart my laptop and connect after 15 minutes. This worked. Also, I restarted my remote Ubuntu PC a couple of times remotely sitting in my home. I would loose connection but after 3-5 minutes I was able to reconnect again.

**Update**: I came to the remote site, the IP address remained same (as I set it manually during Ubuntu installation) and I restarted the PC. There were some BIOS updates (there is Windows OS on this PC as well) and it took good amount to restart. After that, I was able to remote login (from my laptop on the same network in the remote site) into this Ubuntu PC network without any issues. All it needed was a restart and solved the issue.

[image]

Any help on what is wrong here?

Comment: Has the IP address for the remote system changed?

Comment: @roaima I just updated my question with more info. All it needed was a Ubuntu PC restart and then it worked fine. The IP address was static.

Comment: The question I'd want answering them would by why a restart was needed. That's not normal - I have a number of remote systems around the world and i'd be pretty miffed if I needed to keep restarting them to get connectivity (as would my users)

Comment: @roaima `I have a number of remote systems around the world` just wow! so you are the right person I need to answer this. While writing this answer from my home, I now have access to the remote site Ubuntu Desktop. By the way, can you list the settings that you usually do to keep them accessible remotely at all times?

Comment: I don't do anything special. Staying online and operational is the normal expected behaviour

Comment: In my case it is different. I access it through my laptop. I often connect and disconnect the real VNC in a day. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand me. I don't connect to the servers in a daily basis, but when I do I expect them to be online. The servers staying online and operational is the normal expected behaviour

Comment: Have you disabled hibernate/suspend? This coupled with WOL would explain why you can't connect after a period of time but a few minutes later the system is accessible again. Any form of hibernate/suspend must be disabled for remote access servers

Comment: Oh. Is your "update" an answer? If so please remove it from the question and post it a an answer. You'll be able to accept your own answer a day later